# eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be in $GL(2,n)$ means $n$ by $n$ invertible matrix with entries in $Z_2$, If $A$ has eigenvalue $1$, Is there something we can say about structure of matrix $A$ or about $\dim(\ker(I-A))$ or anything else about this matrix?